# build.sbt unresolved dependencies for spark 2.4.3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, build, apache-spark-sql, sbt

I am new to scala and trying to run a Spark App on the cluster with `Scala version 2.11.12` and `spark version 2.4.3` and `JDK 1.8.0_212`. My build.sbt looks like this -

```
name := "LearningScala"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
val sparkVersion = "2.4.3"

//resolvers += "Maven Dependencies" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
)
```

As you can see, I also tried using the `resolvers` but nothing is working. The error log says following are unresolved dependencies -

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.13: configuration not found in org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.13: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.parquet#parquet-hadoop;1.10.1 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.13: configuration not found in org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.13: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.parquet#parquet-hadoop;1.10.1 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient;3.1: configuration not found in commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient;3.1: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;2.6.5 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.2: configuration not found in commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.2: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from commons-configuration#commons-configuration;1.6 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: log4j#log4j;1.2.17: configuration not found in log4j#log4j;1.2.17: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-auth;2.6.5 runtime
[error] unresolved dependency: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.6: configuration not found in commons-lang#commons-lang;2.6: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.orc#orc-mapreduce;1.5.5 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: javax.inject#javax.inject;1: configuration not found in javax.inject#javax.inject;1: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from com.google.inject#guice;3.0 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.7.3: configuration not found in org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.7.3: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.parquet#parquet-hadoop;1.10.1 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: org.lz4#lz4-java;1.4.0: configuration not found in org.lz4#lz4-java;1.4.0: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;2.4.3 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.8: configuration not found in com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.8: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;2.4.3 runtime
[error] unresolved dependency: javax.ws.rs#javax.ws.rs-api;2.0.1: configuration not found in javax.ws.rs#javax.ws.rs-api;2.0.1: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.glassfish.jersey.containers#jersey-container-servlet;2.22.2 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: javax.annotation#javax.annotation-api;1.2: configuration not found in javax.annotation#javax.annotation-api;1.2: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.glassfish.jersey.core#jersey-server;2.22.2 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.Final: configuration not found in javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.Final: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.glassfish.jersey.core#jersey-server;2.22.2 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-json;3.1.5: configuration not found in io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-json;3.1.5:
```

Has someone used 2.11 with 2.4.3? My spark shell shows these values and manually I can import packages like this -

```
$ spark-shell
scala> scala> import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
```

then why build.sbt not able to fetch it?

Comment: I used the same dependencies but with ```scalaVersion  := "2.12.3"``` , it worked for me , could you try again with Scala 2.12.

Comment: Solution Update: In some cases, I have observed that if you are using intellij, then simply delete the project metadata files and directories first. Andnd import the files just one more time. This has also solved the issue for me. The build.sbt would fetch the dependencies without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried to solve this problem: 
I deleted the `~/.ivy2` directory first and then started bumping up the version of Spark from `2.2.0` while keeping `scalaVersion := 2.11.12`. The final version of Spark that worked perfect is `2.4.3`.

Although I tried the trial and error method, I think some of the dependencies that version `2.4.3` could not download earlier was downloaded by its previous versions.

List of Spark Version I tried and ran successfully -

- 2.2.0
- 2.2.1
- 2.3.0
- 2.3.1
- 2.4.0
- 2.4.3

I understand that this is weird but worked for me. I think the issue was with the cached packaged that was already downloaded in the `~/.ivy2` directory. Deleting just the `cache/` inside the `.ivy2` would not help.

Comment: In some cases, I have also observed that if you are using intellij, then simply delete the project metadata and import the files just one more time. This has also solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

remove comment before resolver. Also, try to add the repo in this way

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  DefaultMavenRepository,
  Resolver.bintrayRepo("typesafe", "releases"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.mavenLocal
)
```

Comment: This answer might help the original author's problem, but does not answer the question posed at the end of the post.

Comment: This answer is not something that I was looking for. I wanted to know why build file could not find the dependencies. I think few of the packages went overlapped due to which the newer version of spark skipped them to download and that caused the issue. I deleted ~/.ivy2 directory and started bumping up with the least version that had maximum usage and I got the answer.